# Cannot close form if date field is not valid

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an unbound form that has a date control (dtReportDate). dtReportDate has its validation property set to test for the 15th of the month. If the date is not the 15th the validation fails. In short the validation works as desired.

I also have a close button. However, the form will not close unless the dtReportDate control is null or valid.

In my scenario it is acceptable to close the form without submitting the data so it is not necessary that the date always be valid.

What is the best method to allow the form to close regardless what the date is?

Comment: To close with or without saving the invalid data?

Comment: Clear the fields in the _Unload_ event.

Comment: @Brad this is an unbound form. If the user closes the form nothing is saved.

Comment: @Gustav I will try that next week when I am at work.

Answer (score -1):

Write your own validation procedure.

```
Private Sub dtReportDate_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    With Me.dtReportDate
        If IsDate(.Value) And Day(.Value) <> 15 Then
            MsgBox "Validation failed..."
            .Value = Null   'Clear if needed
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried almost that exact validation procedure but it still would not close because you cannot exit the control.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot exit the control? Of course you can.

Comment: It took me a while to get back to this.  I had Cancel = true, hence I was unable to exit the control. Your code did not include that. I missed it when I first read it.